# How to insert Multiple selected checkbox values in one column

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i want to insert multiple selected checkbox value in one colunm in MS Sql server 2005/08
Eg.
checkboxes are:

Cricket
Football
Painting

Table structure like:

```
    Id | name     | Hobbies
   ----|----------|--------------------------
    1  | Atish    | cricket,football,painting
    2  | Swapnil  | football, painting
```

can you help me?

Comment: Why? Sounds like a non-optimal database design to me. I would have thought separate columns would make more sense or having several related tables. Please provide further details.

Answer (score 3):

There is something called the third normal form: use it :)

Basically this means for you, you need to separate the hobbies from that table, create a seperate table with the possible hobbies and create a lookup-table between the people and the hobbies.

The dirty way would be to define a seperator and insert smth like cricktet|football|painting to the column: but I would really not suggest to do that!

Comment: Thanks MADmap

Can I didnt Do it in the same table. Please suggest me if you know. it would be very kind of you...

Answer (score 0):

You can make three tables

```
[Names]
Name_ID (int)
Name (varchar)

[Hobbies]
Hobby_ID
Hobby (varchar)

[Hobbies_Names]
Name_ID (foreign key)
Hobby_ID (foregin key)
```

So, if Atish, who has Name_ID = 1, and hobbies cricket,football,painting, which have Hobby_ID: 1, 2 and 3, your Hobbies_Names table would look like this:

```
    Name_Id | Hobby_ID
   ---------|----------|
    1       | 1
    1       | 2
    1       | 3
```

Then you could make a SQL query that selects all Hobbies, where Name_ID = 1 for example