# Can we insert Multiple check box Values in One Column?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

i wan to insert multiple selected checkbox values to be inserted in to one column, can we do this. and if we can do it? please let me know how to do it......

thank you..

Comment: Is this similar to other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256170/how-to-insert-multiple-selected-checkbox-values-in-one-column

Answer (score 0):

You could take all of the values and append them to a stringbuilder and then submit that to your db column

Answer (score 0):

Use a Flags-type enum and store the integer value in the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to have these 'multiple check boxes' values predefined then create a separate table for it. Otherwise if they are random, then there shouldn't be a problem. Just read them, append in a string and pass it to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separator (like  $,:,#...) to combine check boxes value and make one string and insert in to column. And when you want to retrieve that value just spilt that string.